# how to display the smallest data in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I need help to get the solution for this condition. 
This is my query :

```
   SELECT a.idbarang, a.nama,b.stokbagus, a.hargaJual , b.exp
   FROM barang a 
   LEFT JOIN detail_barang b on a.idbarang = b.idbarang 
   WHERE a.status = '1'
```

the result :

```
  idbarang   nama              stokbagus   hargaJual  exp
  --------   ----------------  ---------   ---------  ----------
  33001      Pepsi Can 330 Ml     30         900      2015-06-17
  21001      Cheetos 10gr         30         900      2015-12-19
  21001      Cheetos 10gr         25         900      2014-12-07
```

how to display one cheetos that have the smallest 'exp'.
I want to display

```
  idbarang   nama              stokbagus   hargaJual  exp
  --------   ----------------  ---------   ---------  ----------
  33001      Pepsi Can 330 Ml     30         900      2015-06-17
  21001      Cheetos 10gr         25         900      2014-12-07
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display the smallest `exp` for each `nama`, you need to use `GROUP BY`. Try this:

```
SELECT a.idbarang, a.nama,b .stokbagus, a.hargaJual, MIN(b.exp)
FROM barang a
LEFT JOIN detail_barang b ON a.idbarang = b.idbarang
WHERE a.status = '1'
GROUP BY a.idbarang
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order by exp and set the limit to 1, that way only the lowest exp will be shown. It would look like this:

> SELECT a.idbarang, a.nama,b.stokbagus, a.hargaJual , b.exp    FROM
>   barang a     LEFT JOIN detail_barang b on a.idbarang = b.idbarang
>   WHERE a.status = '1' ORDER BY b.exp LIMIT 1;